# JWT token using load balance

Tags: jwt

We have a load balance with multiple servers attached to it.
An initial call to our webapi tier acquires a JWT token that is used in subsequent calls.
The problem is the one JWT acquire from server1 used in server2 and failed authentication.

What are the best practices in a load balance situation ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using frameworks like Laravel for example the JWT token are stored in the cache system the framework uses. Be sure that both server1 and 2 share the cache storage. hope it helps